# Windows 8 Metro - CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync

Tags: c#, windows-8, in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps

I have a free metro app in windows app store.
Now i want to try in-app purchase, so I create a in app purchase item in "Advanced features",
Product ID named "myProduct".

And when i try to buy this item in my program, I call below command:

`string receipt = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("myProduct", true);`

and i got this response :

`「Windows Marketplace」 is no longer available you try to purchase the item.`

So, how can i try my in-app purchase ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing the buy functionality under the app installed FROM the windows store or under the app compiled on your station ? I this is for testing with your local version, you have to use:

```
CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync
```

[References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967810.aspx)